# Why Null Pointer Exception? How does the inflating change on rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

On a specific view I am adding a global layout listener:

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new   ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        // code  
       LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someView);
       if(linearLayout != null && linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)   {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      LinearLayout otherLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.someOtherView);  
otherLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
//other code  
        }  
    });
```

In some cases but I don't know exactly how, during rotation some times it happens that there is NPE for the line `otherLayout.setVisibility(GONE)`

To be honest I am not sure why the code checks for `null` in the lines above for the `linearLayout` and not for the `otherLayout` but both are defined in the same resource file and are not e.g. removed programmatically anywhere.
The only difference is that the `otherLayout` is not visible.

So my question is: Are there any things I should look out for on rotation with global layout listeners? Why am I getting NPE in some random cases?

**Update:**
Both views are part of the same xml file. And actually one defined is after the other. The only difference is that someView is defined as visible and otherView as not visible. Having said that though, there can be such a case where someView is already visible/rendered while otherView has not been yet rendered/made visible when the rotation is happening depending on the current width

Comment: Are you sure that both layouts (portrait and landscape) have the fields? Have you considered unregistering the listener in the onDestroy method and assigning a new one in the onCreate?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos:1) I don't see a layout specifically for landscape. So I assume the same is used for landscape and portrait? 2) Assign a new one on `onCreate` or `onCreateView`? Right now it is assigned `onCreateView`

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos: But what is the issue here that you recommend these? I mean why do I get the NPE? What am I missing/not taking into account?

Comment: Is NPE stands for Null Pointer Exception? never heard of this abbrev before.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid:Yes. It is a very common term in Java lingo

Comment: @Jim are you sure that you should be using the globalLayoutListener like that? Why can't you go with another alternative?

Comment: Well you activity will be recreated on rotation, if your listener lives after the activity ondestroy then the fields of the reference will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is a difference between the layouts of `findViewById(R.id.someView)` and `findViewById(R.id.someOtherView)`. The difference is the timing, for sure, and possibly the layout xml file that it is inflating. With R.id.`someOtherView`, it is done immediately while R.id.`someView`, it is executed when the layout is drawn OR at any other time as in screen orientation change since the *width/height of the screen changed.*

**NEW**:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someView);

myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new   ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {  
     //LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.someView);
     if(linearLayout != null && linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)   {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
...
  }  
});
```

Notes:

- I commented out the findViewById() inside onGlobalLayout(), basically removing it.
- I think it's not safe to call findViewById() inside the listener since *layouts cannot be cached*, similar to views and anything related to UI objects. This is what I meant above on my last sentence. I know it's not obvious. I think this explains that the issue is not consistent or strange, as you said essentially.

Comment: @Jim, I am thinking why not remove the listener OnGlobalLayoutListener? Do you really need it to be persistent for a long time? By removing the listener, you won't have to worry about this problem anymore, I believe.

Comment: Both views are part of the same xml file. And actually one is after the other. The only difference is that `someView` is defined as visible and `otherView` as not visible. Having said that though, there can be such a case where `someView` *is* already visible/rendered while `otherView` has not been yet rendered/made visible when the rotation is happening. And in a sense your last sentence is correct because inside the global listener if the width of the layout has been reduced when the screen is in landscape only then the `otherView` is made visible. But how does this affect everything?

Comment: What exactly am I doing wrong? I can unregister on destroy sure, but I also would like to understand what is the core issue

Comment: @Jim, I added sample code and comments under the NEW section.

Comment: So `findViewById` uses caching? But when I assign it to a `final` variable outside the listener, is it not cached also?

Comment: @Jim, findViewById depends on the layout you inflated, that is the View object. So yes, I consider the View is cached. Do you think so now? About your second question, I think you have a valid question. At least this way, you're telling Java VM to keep the View object in memory.

Comment: @Jim, My experience with this is that I called removeOnGlobalLayoutListener() inside onGlobalLayout() after I get some screen configurations. So I don't have your problem and the listener is deactivated after the first trigger.

Comment: Actually I do deregister the listener also, but *after* these lines of code. So in this case it crashes just a few lines *before* the listener is deregistered. Concerning the assigning to the `final` is this a “trick”/hack?

Comment: @Jim, The final declaration is required because linearLayout object is used in the inner class when it is declared outside of it. The inner class can refer to any variable/objects outside of it but it has to be non-dynamic or "final". Perhaps this is another hint that inner classes do not want anything dynamic in value, contents, or reference.